# How can I see the image with CloudFront URL?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a bucket that has images uploaded with `--acl public-read`, so I can see the image when I use the s3 bucket link. However, when I use the CloudFront URL, it 307s. More strange is that my website is able to load the images, but not when I access it directly through the browser. How can I fix this? I am not even sure how to debug this.

Comment: How long ago did you create this bucket?  CloudFront → S3 needs some time to coalesce for new buckets that are not in us-east-1 because of the way `example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` is updated in DNS after bucket creation.

Comment: Bucket has been there for weeks. I think its a permission issue, but don't really know how to check. I think the bucket needs to allow cloudfront to access images directly some how.

Comment: But a 307?  I can't think of anything permissions-related that could return a 307.  Unless of course that's cached.  Check for an `Age` header... even better, show all the response headers (or as much as practical).

Comment: The headers you've whitelisted for forwarding could explain the behavior discrepancy (site link vs direct).

Comment: Okay my images are getting a 200 now via CloudFront, but... the response is my html index instead of the image which is confusing. I should add that I have behaviour to forward all 403s to my index.html.

Comment: Probably best to turn off the custom error document and set the error caching minimim ttl for 403 to 0, temporarily, for troubleshooting.  I don't like the 403 to index hack, anyway.  There are better solutions, like S3 website endpoints with S3 redirect routing rules and/or Lambda@Edge.

Comment: Routing rules are initially counter-intuitive (object keys don't actually have a leading slash) but here's a potentially useful example: https://serverfault.com/a/633571/153161

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot What's the difference between 403 redirect in CF vs Redirect Rules in S3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177848/discussion-between-strawberry-and-michael-sqlbot).

Comment: wat about policy?